# How to add license key for jxbrowser for netbeans java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jxbrowser, license-key

I am trying to add jxbrowser in my java application but I can't run my application as it keeps telling me that my license is not found. I got a free license from the website which I can't show the license key here at the code below, but I want to ask how do I configure and set the license key because I keep getting an error which. you refer to below. I want to know if I am setting the license correctly in my case. I replaced the license key with all "#" if you see below because I can't let people look at it in case it gets stolen. Do let me know of how to fix my problem.

```
public class locate extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    /**
     * Creates new form locate
     */
    public locate() {
        initComponents();
        open_site();
    }

    Browser browser;
    BrowserView view;
    private void open_site(){
        Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(
        EngineOptions.newBuilder(HARDWARE_ACCELERATED)
    .licenseKey("##############################################################")
                .build());
        System.setProperty("jxbrowser.license.key", "###########################################################");
        //BrowserUtil;
        browser = new Browser();
        view = new BrowserView(browser);
        GoogleMapsPanel.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        browser.addTitleListener((TitleEvent evt) -> {
            setTitle(evt.getTitle());
        });
        
        browser.addConsoleListener((ConsoleEvent evt) -> {
            System.out.println("LOG: " + evt.getMessage());
        });
                
        browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent evt){
                evt.getBrowser().setZoomLevel(-2);
            }
        });
        
        browser.loadURL("/Users/jacksonseow/NetBeansProjects/PleaseWork/src/pleasework/googlemaps.html");
                
                
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.getDefault(SourceFile:89)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext.<init>(SourceFile:61)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext.<clinit>(SourceFile:29)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:296)
    at pleasework.locate.open_site(locate.java:241)
    at pleasework.locate.<init>(locate.java:37)
    at pleasework.locate$7.run(locate.java:324)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JxBrowser license check failed: No valid license found.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the given source code I see that you mix JxBrowser 7 and 6 in a single Java application. The following code belongs to 7:

```java
Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(
        EngineOptions.newBuilder(HARDWARE_ACCELERATED)
                .licenseKey("###############")
                .build());
```

The lines below belong to JxBrowser 6:

```java
browser = new Browser();
view = new BrowserView(browser);
```

JxBrowser 7 and 6 use the different license keys. I assume you requested a free 30-days evaluation key for JxBrowser 7 and trying to use it with JxBrowser 6. It won't work that way. If you have a valid license key for JxBrowser 7 then you shouldn't use JxBrowser 6.

I suggest that you update your example and use only JxBrowser 7 in your Java app:

```java
Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(
        EngineOptions.newBuilder(HARDWARE_ACCELERATED)
                .licenseKey("########")
                .build());
System.setProperty("jxbrowser.license.key", "##########");
//BrowserUtil;
Browser browser = engine.newBrowser();
BrowserView view = BrowserView.newInstance(browser);
GoogleMapsPanel.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
browser.on(TitleChanged.class, event -> setTitle(evt.getTitle()));
browser.on(ConsoleMessageReceived.class, event -> 
        System.out.println("LOG: " + evt.getMessage()));

browser.navigation().on(FrameLoadFinished.class, event -> {
    event.frame().browser().zoom().level(ZoomLevel.P_80);
});
browser.navigation().loadUrl("/Users/jacksonseow/NetBeansProjects/PleaseWork/src/pleasework/googlemaps.html");
```

More details on how to switch from JxBrowser 6 to 7 API you can find in our migration guide at: https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/migration/v6-v7.html